# Cambiar valores por descripciones en Query/Dashboard

Tags: genexus

Tengo un objeto Query en el cual estoy agrupando por día de la semana, usando DOW().

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me devuelve de manera correcta los valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de mostrar los nombres de los días en lugar de los números?
Intenté con la propiedad Values Style, pero por lo que vi es para agregar estilos CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas?

Hay dos maneras para lograr esto:

1. Definiendo en la transacción el atributo dia de la semana como una fórmula y basándolo en un dominio enumerado con los nombres de los dias de la semana (el objeto query toma esa definición y usa los nombres en vez de los números).
2. Si no queres definir el atributo podes hacer la conversion de numeros a nombres de dia directamente en la query, y para esto hay dos maneras

   2.a) Usando la funcion iif, te quedaria algo asi:

Iif(DoW(TurFec) = 1, "Lunes", Iif(DoW(TurFec) = 2, "Martes", Iif(DoW(TurFec) = 3, "Miércoles", ...)))

2.b) usando IF, y te quedaría algo así:

"Lunes" IF DoW(TurFec) = 1; "Martes" IF DoW(TurFec) = 2; ...; "Sábado" IF DoW(TurFec) = 6; "Domingo" OTHERWISE

La opcion 1) esta desde hace varias versiones.

La opcion 2) esta desde v16u11

Comment: Impecable, estuve buscando documentación sobre la sintaxis en el objeto Query y encontré poco y nada.